# autoWebview does not seem to work for Appium/android

Tags: android, appium

For some reason, when I pass the autoWebview capability, it doesn't seem to work.  I used Appium Desktop and Inspector to look at the elements, but it treats the webview as a single element and won't let me choose anything inside of it. here are my capabilities:

```
{
  "deviceName": "ZY333VMBDL",
  "platformName": "android",
  "platformVersion": "7.0",
  "app": "tmp/mobile.apk",
  "autoWebview": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.  Appium told me I had two contexts to choose from -- NATIVEAPP and WEBVIEW_chrome.  I did:

`session.setContext('WEBVIEW_chrome');`

and it appears to have switched to that context.